# How to have two different bgcolor changing events

Tags: javascript, events

I'm trying to have a bgcolor change for an element on mouseover, mouseout, and onclick. The problem is Javascript overwrites my onclick with mouseout, so I can't have both. So is there any way to have mouseover reset after mouseout?

```js
        function init() {
          document.getElementById('default').onmouseover = function() {
            tabHoverOn('default', 'grey')
          };
          document.getElementById('default').onmouseout = function() {
            tabHoverOff('default', 'yellow')
          };
          document.getElementById('section2').onmouseover = function() {
            tabHoverOn('section2', 'grey')
          };
          document.getElementById('section2').onmouseout = function() {
            tabHoverOff('section2', 'yellow')
          };
          document.getElementById('section3').onmouseover = function() {
            tabHoverOn('section3', 'grey')
          };
          document.getElementById('section3').onmouseout = function() {
            tabHoverOff('section3', 'yellow')
          };
        }


        function tabHoverOn(id, bgcolor) {
          document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor = bgcolor;
        }

        function tabHoverOff(id, bgcolor) {
          document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor = bgcolor;
        }
        var current = document.getElementById('default');

        function tab1Highlight(id) {

          if (current != null) {
            current.className = "";
          }
          id.className = "tab1highlight";
          current = id;
        }

        function tab2highlight(id) {

          if (current != null) {
            current.className = "";
          }
          id.className = "tab2highlight";
          current = id;
        }

        function tab3highlight(id) {
          if (current != null) {
            current.className = "";
          }
          id.className = "tab3highlight";
          current = id;
        }
        window.onload = init();
```

```css
body {
  width: 900px;
  margin: 10px auto;
}
nav {
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
nav > ul {
  list-style: none;
}
nav > ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 3px;
  width: 150px;
}
nav > ul > li > a {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ffff66;
  border: 1px solid #9b9b9b;
  border-radius: 12px 8px 0 0;
  padding: 8px 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
}
main {
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid #9b9b9b;
  padding: 10px;
}
main > h1 {
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
.tab1highlight {
  background-color: #339966;
  color: white;
}
.tab2highlight {
  background-color: #ff6666;
  color: white;
}
.tab3highlight {
  background-color: #6600ff;
  color: white;
}
main img {
  border: 5px solid #eeefff;
  width: 80%;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<body>
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#sec1" id="default" onclick="tab1Highlight(this)">Section 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#sec2" id="section2" onclick="tab2highlight(this)">Section 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#sec3" id="section3" onclick="tab3highlight(this)">Section 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<main>
    <h1>Exercise: Navigation Tab #5</h1>
    <ul>
        <li>
            Combine the navigation tab exercises #1, #3, and #4 in one file, including <br>
            <ul>
                <li>temporarily change the background color of a tab when the cursor is hovering on it.</li>
                <li>set the foreground and background color of the tab being clicked.</li>
                <li>change the background color of the main element based on the selected tab.</li>
            </ul>
            <p>
                To test, click on a tab and then move your mouse around.  For example, the third tab is clicked, the tab background color is switched to blue.  Then hover the mouse over the third tab, the background color of the tab should be switch to light green and then back to blue after the mouse moves out.
            </p>

            <img src="menu_tab5.jpg">


        </li>
    </ul>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try updating a Boolean variable.

```
var Ele = document.getElementById('default');
var clicked = false;

Ele.onclick = function(){
    clicked = true;
    // add additional functionality here
}
Ele.onmouseover = function(){
    clicked = false;
    // add additional functionality here
}
Ele.onmouseout = function(){
    if(!clicked){
    // add additional functionality here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's generally a good idea to keep CSS out of JavaScript completely if you can help it. A better strategy for solving the hover problem is to use the CSS pseudo selector [`:hover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover) rather than coding the color changes in JavaScript. If you give all your tabs the same class, you only have to write the CSS once:

```
.tab {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.tab:hover {
  background-color: grey;
}
```

Once you've done that, you can also relegate the click styling to CSS by creating an event handler that adds and removes a special class each time a tab is clicked.

In the CSS file:

```
.tab.clicked {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

And then in JavaScript, something like:

```
var tabs = document.getElementsByClassName('tab');
for (i = 0; i < tabs.length; i ++) {
  tabs[i].onclick = function (ev) {
    for (i = 0; i < tabs.length; i ++) {
      tabs[i].classList.remove('clicked');
    }
    ev.currentTarget.classList.add('clicked');
  };
}
```

I've created a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/12z5zw0t) to illustrate.

Comment: the problem is it's a school assignment and I can't have any static hovers. I can only have DHTML events.

Comment: `:hover` is definitely part of DHTML. But if the assignment specifically says not to use `:hover`, then the same logic applies (adding and removing classes), just make the specificity higher on the `.clicked` CSS rule and then it will take precedence over the `.hover` class style rules. 

Even if you can't use `:hover`, you shouldn't mix style and functionality unless you absolutely have to. And if the assignment is forcing you to, at least recognize that this is a bad practice and should not be replicated in the future.

Comment: Thank you for your help! But how do you assign levels of specificity?

Comment: Specificity is the tricky part of CSS that most people like to ignore. There's a good article about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity). 

But basically, by saying "make the specificity higher", I mean in your stylesheet, the rule for hovering should just be `.hover { ... }`, but the rule for clicking should be `a.clicked { ... }`, that way when the two are in conflict, the `.clicked` style overrides the `.hover` style because the `a.clicked` rule is written in a more specific way (because it specifies both an element and a class).